# The best Gigabit Ethernet switch for Intel(R) 82579 lm Gigabit card

Tags: ethernet

I have 12 PCs ,each of which has Intel(R) 82579 lm Gigabit network connection card.
What is the best Gigabit  Ethernet switch to connect them,please ?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/ would be a better place to ask that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at belows:

- [NETGEAR ProSAFE FS116NA 16-Port Fast Ethernet Switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000063UZW)
- [TP-LINK TL-SG1016D 10/100/1000Mbps 16-Port Gigabit 13-inch
  Rackmountable Switch, 32Gbps Capacity](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004ELA0SS)

But note there no best. The best depending from what you are looking for.
Like managed/unmanaged, how many ports, etc.